# Show image or video depending on Content-Type in React-Native

Tags: facebook, react-native, react-native-ios

I would like to show to the user, in my react-native app, an element reachable on a specific url such as: `https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/somebucket/somekey`

This object has a Content-Type that can be `image/jpeg` or `video/mp4`.

If it is an image, it has to be printed in an `<Image>` component from https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/image.html.

If it is a video, it has to be shown in a `<Video>` component from https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-video

What is a clean way to show this media without downloading it in a first place (the video can be seen as a stream in `<Video>`) and without knowing its `Content-Type`?

Right, the solution that I have found is to do a `HEAD` request on the media to get the `Content-Type` and then accessing it from the proper React component. Would you have a better solution to avoid this `HEAD` request?

Comment: I vote up for HEAD request and having a conditional render according `Content-Type`

Comment: Where do you get those URLs from in the first place, that you don’t know what they represent? Will you only be showing one particular such URL to one single user a single time? If not, it might make more sense if you involved a server-side component, that can cache the result of the HEAD request, so that you don’t have to perform one on every single view ...

Comment: My server is generating a signed URL and then the client can upload whatever he wants from the App Camera so it can be either video or picture on that URL.
What I might be able to do is to generate that URL  once that the media has been recorded, so at this moment, I know which kind of element it is. I did not want to change that logic but it might make more sense

Comment: Hi, i am curious how did you solve your issue, or what was the preferable approach for you. I wanted to do the same thing, according to content i wanna apply video/img tag or i wonder if there is a plugin we could use, whatever type of source is we could use for display